# Type of component in multimeter

Tags: identification, multimeter

What kind of component is marked SC2? There are no markings on it. How can I know the characteristics about it?

The components are located in the multimeter immediately after the input pins.

[image]

Comment: Could be a gas discharge tube

Comment: may be a spark gap